# Including .init_array section to Linker script produces unusable output

Tags: c++, riscv, linker-scripts

I try to port a c++ project to RISC-V. The project was already successfully compiled for ARM using IAR Toolchain and for Windows.

For the RISC-V port I have written my own CRT0.S file which does all the initialization and also my own linker script.

With some small demo projects everything is working perfectly.
I can also successfully compile and link the project. The problem is when I add the .init_array section to the linker script the output file increases from about 4k to more than 100k. I added these sections to the linker script:

```
.preinit_array     :
{
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
  KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
} > ram

.init_array     :
{
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
  KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
  KEEP (*(.init_array ))
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
} > ram

.fini_array     :
{
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
  KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
  KEEP (*(.fini_array ))
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
} > ram
```

When I now try to load this ELF file to GDB I just get the error **No Registers**. When I remove the sections from the linker I can successfully run the code as far as i don't use static objects which are not loaded.

Is there any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: init array design is architecture specific. It differs for example between x86 and ARM. Are you sure risc-v uses the ARM style init arrays? What other architecture specific sections for risc-v are you missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to identify the problem. When adding the init array section, some static objects from the standard libraries were added as well. The library was using system calls to the operating system (ebreak). Because we are working on a bare metal system the calls were not caught.

The solution was to exclude the standard library and implement the `delete` operator manually. Now it is working perfectly.

```
void operator delete(void *p) noexcept
{
    free(p);
}

extern "C" void operator delete(void* p, unsigned long c) noexcept
{
    operator delete(p); // Same as regular delete
}
```